# Существуют ли в Android способ создать диалог с 2 кнопками и(!) крестиком в правом верхнем углу без кастомного layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog

Нужно создать диалог, оповещение+ 2 кнопки + крестик в правом углу закрывающий, по которому диалог будет закрываться БЕЗ кастомного layout.То есть через AlertDialog.Builder.
Благодарю

Comment: Такой как тут? http://technxt.net/how-to-implement-alert-dialog-box-in-android-using-android-studio/ а зачем вам кнопка в правом верхнем углу? это не в стиле Андроида, просто сделайте закрытие при нажатии вне диалога

Comment: Такой как по ссылке,только ещё с крестиком в правом углу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без кастомного layout не обойтись.

Пример кастомного layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_24px"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Кнопка 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Кнопка 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Почитайте про [диалоговые окна](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru), скорее всего вопросы отпадут.